# Mysql query join tables is unable to use where condition

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am developing a Wordpress website, I need to get join table values using where condition.Now I can able to get values with out using where but its showing multiple values, I didn't get correspond values for particular id. If i use where i am getting error. I have given below my code.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
    wp_candiform.numFormCand,
    wp_candiform.questionCand,
    wp_candiform.civilCand,

    wp_diplom.annee,
    wp_diplom.titre,
    wp_diplom.nive,

    wp_formation.CandFDQ,
    wp_formation.titreCandFDQ,
    wp_formation.mention,

    wp_confirmation.etatand,
    wp_confirmation.comment,
    wp_confirmation.etat1Cand

    FROM wp_candiform
    INNER JOIN wp_diplom ON wp_candiform.user_id = wp_diplom .user_id
    JOIN wp_formation ON wp_candiform.user_id = wp_formation .user_id
    JOIN wp_confirmation ON wp_candiform.user_id = wp_confirmation .user_id
    WHERE user_id='$user_id'"
    );
```

Comment: Please provide the sql error.

Comment: on where clause use table alias so it become `WHERE wp_candiform.user_id='$user_id'`

Comment: You using JOIN that equals INNER JOIN. You will not get some crossing data. Try using LEFT JOIN

Comment: There's a space in between these three `wp_diplom .user_id`, `wp_formation .user_id` and `wp_confirmation .user_id` .. is that a typo?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'JOIN wp_formation ON wp_candiform.user_id = wp_formation' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Since you are joining tables, you need to mention which table's userid is compared in the Where condition.

While using the where condition, you need to add the table alias to the Where condition.

Refer to the below code.

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT 
    wp_candiform.numFormCand,
    wp_candiform.questionCand,
    wp_candiform.civilCand,

    wp_diplom.annee,
    wp_diplom.titre,
    wp_diplom.nive,

    wp_formation.CandFDQ,
    wp_formation.titreCandFDQ,
    wp_formation.mention,

    wp_confirmation.etatand,
    wp_confirmation.comment,
    wp_confirmation.etat1Cand

    FROM wp_candiform
    INNER JOIN wp_diplom ON wp_candiform.user_id = wp_diplom .user_id
    JOIN wp_formation ON wp_candiform.user_id = wp_formation .user_id
    JOIN wp_confirmation ON wp_candiform.user_id = wp_confirmation .user_id
    WHERE wp_candiform.user_id='$user_id'"
    );
```

Comment: Hi Thank you for your reply, I have tried this code but i didn't get any values

Comment: This is how the code goes. You need to make sure there are no other errors or make sure there is data available in DB for this combination of queries!

Comment: Thank you for your replay, already I have resolved this issue

Comment: If this answer provided any help, then do mark this answer as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine in your code just a minor mistake in query. At the end

```
WHERE user_id='$user_id'
```

to

```
WHERE wp_candiform.user_id='$user_id'
```